# Listen the status of location service with React Native Expo (not permissions)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, expo

Imagine that the user is using a map that requires the location to be active, and if not, the map will be closed.

Is there any way to listen to the Location status using Location.hasServicesEnabledAsync()?

Comment: I think there's no such listener currently. I would suggest something like checking `hasServicesEnabledAsync` after not receiving a location update for a few seconds. You can achieve that by having a recursive timeout which gets reset on each location update.

Answer (score 0):

Working with:

```
_getLocationAsync = async () => {
    let { status } = await 
Permissions.askAsync(Permissions.LOCATION);
    if (status !== 'granted') {
        alert('The request was denied');
    }else{
        try{
            let location = await Location.getCurrentPositionAsync({});
            // do something with location
         }catch(e){
            alert('We could not find your position. Please make sure your 
         location service provider is on');
            console.log('Error while trying to get location: ', e);
         }
    }
}
```